# active states interfering with each other

Tags: javascript, css

I have 2 chunks of CSS that have an active state applied to them, only since adding the second chunk of CSS, the active state on one of them is showing on the other (a minus symbol is showing up when my JS 'fade-in on scroll' happens). Does anyone know how to apply an active state to just one class? Seems like it would be obvious but I can't find it anywhere online.

Thanks for any help! :)

https://staging-unilab-uk-com.stackstaging.com/home/

```
 /* FADE-IN ITEMS ON SCROLL */           

.fade-in {
  opacity:0;
  transform: translateY(40%);
  transition: all 2s ease-out;
}

.active {
  opacity: 4;
  transform: translateY(0);
}

 /* COLLAPSIBLE BUTTONS */ 

.collapsible:after {
  content: '\002B';  /* -----PLUS SIGN----- */
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212"; /* -----MINUS SIGN----- */
}
```

Comment: Change the second `.active:after` to `.collapsible.active:after`. Also, to be more correct, all your `:after`s should be `::after`.

Comment: Find a way to make things more specific see e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: Amazing thank you! Should I also change the other .active to 'fade-in::active' ? Because if I add any more CSS with active states then the same issue might happen again, is it good practice to always assign the active to a class?

Comment: _"is it good practice to always assign the active to a class?"_ - that phrasing makes little sense - both `fade-in` and `active` _are_ classes. What you are doing with `.collapsible.active`, is create a _selector_, that matches elements that have _both_ of those classes. If you want the rule to apply only to such elements, then this isn't so much just a "good practice", but simply a _necessity_.

Comment: The code I'm using is from w3chools (I think), But something that has got me a little confused is they have put .active as a class, but there is also the :active selector. Why would they name it this way? or is it just preference? are .active and :active trying to achieve the same thing? Sorry not sure if that makes sense